# How to extract Timesheet data using Rally WS API?

Tags: node.js, rally

I want all the time entries between two specific dates, regardless of the time they were entered. Must I query the time entry items, then get the _ref value for the values in separate requests.

Is there a more efficient way to get to the hours?
Maybe an example piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you choose to start with a TimeEntryItem and traverse to TimeEntryValues, or the other way around, depends on the problem you are trying to solve. If, for example, you would like to aggregate time, you may choose Item -> Values direction.

Here are two examples written with [Rally REST tookit for  Node](https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node):

```
var rally = require('rally'),
    queryUtils = rally.util.query,
    restApi = rally({
        user: 'user@co.com', 
        pass: 'secret', 
        apiVersion: 'v2.0', 
        server: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com',  
        requestOptions: {
            headers: {
                'X-RallyIntegrationName': 'Timesheet data: from TEItem to TEValue',  
                'X-RallyIntegrationVendor': 'Rally',             
                'X-RallyIntegrationVersion': '1.0'                    
            },
        }
    });

function getTimeEntryValues(result) {
    for(var i = 0, length = result.Results.length; i < length; i++){
        console.log(result.Results[i].Values._ref);
        getValue(result.Results[i].Values._ref);
    }

}

function getValue(ref){
     restApi.query({
            ref: ref,
            fetch: ['Hours', 'DateVal']
    },
    function(error, result){
        if(error) {
            onError(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Success!', result)
        }
    });
}

 function getTimeEntryItems(callback) {

   var query = queryUtils.where('WeekStartDate', '>=','2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' );
   query = query.and('WeekStartDate', '<=','2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z' );
    restApi.query({
        type: 'TimeEntryItem',
        start: 1,
        limit: Infinity,
        fetch: ['Values', 'TaskDisplayString', 'WorkProductDisplayString'],
        scope: {
            workspace: '/workspace/12352608129', 
            up: false, 
            down: false 
    },
        query: query
    },  function(error, result) {
            if(error) {
            onError(error);
        } else {
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}

function onSuccess(result) {
    console.log('Success!', result);
}

function onError(errors) {
    console.log('Failure!', errors);
}

getTimeEntryItems(getTimeEntryValues);
```

Here is a second example that queries on TimeEntryValues first and then queries on TimeEntryItems:

```
var rally = require('rally'),
    queryUtils = rally.util.query,
    restApi = rally({
        user: 'user@co.com', 
        pass: 'secret', 
        apiVersion: 'v2.0', 
        server: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com',  
        requestOptions: {
            headers: {
                'X-RallyIntegrationName': 'Timesheet data node.js program',  
                'X-RallyIntegrationVendor': 'Rally',             
                'X-RallyIntegrationVersion': '1.0'                    
            },
        }
    });

 function getTimeEntryValues() {

    var query = queryUtils.where('DateVal', '>=','2014-01-08T00:00:00.000Z' );
    query = query.and('DateVal', '<=','2014-01-10T00:00:00.000Z' );
    return restApi.query({
        type: 'TimeEntryValues',
        start: 1,
        limit: Infinity,
        fetch: ['TimeEntryItem', 'Hours'],
        scope: {
            workspace: '/workspace/12352608129', 
            up: false, 
            down: false 
    },
        query: query
    });
}


function getTimeEntryItems(result) {
    var timeEntryItems = [];
    for(var i = 0, length = result.Results.length; i < length; i++){
        console.log(result.Results[i].TimeEntryItem._ref.split("/").pop());
        timeEntryItems.push(result.Results[i].TimeEntryItem._ref.split("/").pop()); //get ObjectID from _ref, since _ref is not queriable

    }
    console.log('object ids of time entry items: ', timeEntryItems);

    var query = queryUtils.where('ObjectID', '=',timeEntryItems[0]);
    for (var i = 1, length = timeEntryItems.length; i < length; i++) {
        query = query.or('ObjectID', '=',timeEntryItems[i]);
    }
    return restApi.query({
            type: 'TimeEntryItem',
            fetch: ['TaskDisplayString', 'WorkProductDisplayString', 'WeekStartDate'], 
            query: query,
    });

}

function onSuccess(result) {
    console.log('Success!', result);
}

function onError(errors) {
    console.log('Failure!', errors);
}

getTimeEntryValues()
    .then(getTimeEntryItems)
    .then(onSuccess)
    .fail(onError);
```